# Set Default dates in EXCEL/VBA

Tags: excel, vba, default

I have Excel/ VBA application, which runs a query based on start and end dates supplied. The start and end dates are supplied on Excel Sheet itself (not forms).
Requirement is to set default Start date to 1st of Month and end date to yesterday date, but user should be able to overwrite the dates.

I am able to set the default Start and End dates by using formulae, but if we overwrite it and input some other date then the formulae saved in it are gone. 
Please guide how to handle this issue.

Comment: Have a "reset" macro that overwrites any manual entries with the formula? Where are you stuck exactly? Got any code?

Comment: @Mat, just saw your comment! I am new to VBA, could you please guide where would to write reset macro and how to fire it? I want to put something like:     If Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C3").Value = "" Then
     Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C3").Value = TODAY()-1
    End If

Answer (score 1):

I usually solve this issue by using another column or cell and I control the output by some IF formula, where the user override has higher priority, and the formula default has lower. Something like:

`IF(UserOverride<>"", UserOverride, FormulaDefault)`

EDIT:
You can attach this code to some button/shortcut

```
Public Sub resetDefaults()
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(5, 5).Formula = "=TODAY()-1"
End Sub
```

Comment: I am thinking if something like on Form_Load we could set default dates. Not sure how this is done in VBA. I am trying following but not working:
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

    If Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C3").Value = "" Then
     Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C3").Value = TODAY()-1
    End If

End Sub

Comment: Is there any equivalent of Form_load in Excel/VBA?

Comment: Why do you mention `Form_Load` if you don't want to use forms? Do you mean "how do I run a macro when the workbook opens"? You can google that exact question and get an answer in under 10 seconds.

Comment: @SilverFish You can add a button to the worksheet named something like: "Restore default dates" and no matter what is in the cell, reenter the formula with defaults.